# Kali Linux Update Fails

Tags: kali-linux

```
Error http://http.kali.org kali/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Fetched 1,673 B in 42s (39 B/s)
W: GPG error: http:// http. kali. org kali Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1425567400 KEYEXPIRED 1425567400 KEYEXPIRED 1425567400
W: GPG error: http://security. kali. org kali/updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1425567400 KEYEXPIRED 1425567400 KEYEXPIRED 1425567400
W: Failed to fetch copy:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/http.kali.org_kali_dists_kali_main_binary-amd64_Packages  Encountered a section with no Package: header
W: Failed to fetch http:// http. kali. org/kali/dists/kali/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

root@kali:~#
```

How can I update my Kali repo?

Comment: I want to know how can I update my Kali repo?

Comment: I used the command
apt-get update

Answer (score 4):

You can inspect the apt-keyring with: `apt-key list`

This should fix your issue:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 7D8D0BF6
```

Then do `aptitude update` (this was useful for me and fix my problem with expired keys. In the link appears other solutions, try it if you want)

Source: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?24687-Problem-with-apt-get-update

Answer (score 1):

The single most common causes of a broken Kali Linux installation are following unofficial advice, and particularly arbitrarily populating the system’s sources.list file with unofficial repositories. The following post aims to clarify what repositories should exist in sources.list, and when they should be used.

[You can get the New Repos Here](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories)

Answer (score 1):

open you terminal and type those text in below

```
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

or

```
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://http.kali.org/ /kali main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/ /wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main/debian-installer
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main/debian-installer
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 1):

Download the tor browser package (from [https://www.torproject.org/](https://www.torproject.org), configure proxychains to match it, then try to update via 'proxychains apt-get ...' The bottom of */etc/proxychains.conf* should read:

```
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
#socks4     127.0.0.1 9050
socks5  127.0.0.1 9150
```

It's not a sources list error. The system is saying that the page/domain isn't there (error 404). I've been getting the same for about a month, but the install worked correctly for a time and I didn't modify sources.list. BTW, I cannot connect consistently via 'proxychains apt-get update/upgrade/dist-upgrade', sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

It appears more like the domain is being blocked by the ISP or at the source than any local error...

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS IT WORKS**

If you try to update Kali with

```
apt-get update
```

and you see these errors:

```
W: GPG error: http:// http. kali. org kali Release:  
The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1425567400 KEYEXPIRED 1425567400 KEYEXPIRED 1425567400
W: GPG error: http://security. kali. org kali/updates Release:  
The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1425567400 KEYEXPIRED 1425567400 KEYEXPIRED 1425567400
```

This is the solution:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
apt-get update
apt-get install kali-archive-keyring
apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys all you have to do is go to the kali linux website and get the repositorys from there i was having the same problem for an hour and after looking into some forums i got a link just open up terminal then type gedit etc/apt/sources.list open sources.list then delete all of the text there then copy and paste

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib

deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free

( BUT WITHOUT THE SPACE IN BETWEEN THE TWO SOURCES SO THEY WILL BE STACKED ON EACH OTHER ) next click file in the top left of the window click save then close the file next go back into terminal then type

```
apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

-Hope this helped if it didnt leave a comment telling me what happened and ill get back to you as soon as possible :D

Answer (score 0):

In official site say:

> On a standard, clean install of Kali Linux, you should have the
>   following two entries present in /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

I had the same problem (404  Not Found in some repositories) and I changed it and Kali 1 work great again!